# The dual representation matrix is the conjugate transpose of the rep matrix acting from right?

Tags: matrices, representation-theory

> **My question is essentially**: Is the dual representation matrix for a complex representation space, just the conjugate transpose of the representation matrix, where we act this dual representation matrix **from the right** of the dual vectors. (The body of the question entails a real representation space, where it seems that we have $v'$ a dual space vector, and $v'M^T M v = v'(v)$.)

Say that I have $S_2$ with representation space $\Bbb C\cong \Bbb R[i]$ such that I can look at a degree $2$ real representation with basis $\{1,i\}$, where $\rho_{(1)(2)}=I_{2\times 2}$ and $$\rho_{(12)}=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},$$
I want to find the dual representation. Let $V=\Bbb R^2$ and write $\{e_1,e_2\}$ for the basis, and the dual vectorspace $V'$ with basis $\{e^1,e^2\}$. Write $\rho:S_2\to GL(V),\qquad \rho':S_2\to GL(V')$.

I took for an example $$\begin{bmatrix}x'&y'\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=x'x+y'y=(x'e^1+y'e^2)(xe_1+ye_2)$$

and now applying our $\rho_{(12)}$: $$\rho_{(12)}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}-y\\x\end{bmatrix}$$

and we want to have for all $q'\in V'$ and $q\in V$ that $$\rho_s'(q')(\rho_s q)= q'(q),$$

so we want to act $\rho_s'$ on $\begin{bmatrix}x&y\end{bmatrix}$ as above so that we have $\rho_s'(\begin{bmatrix}x&y\end{bmatrix})\begin{bmatrix}-y\\x\end{bmatrix} = x'x+y'y$ which makes me think we can just take:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x&y\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}^T=\rho_s'(\begin{bmatrix}x&y\end{bmatrix}),$$

Is that correct? The dual representation works by acting the dual vector from the right on the transpose of the first representation matrix?

But then I think to myself that the easy proof would simply be to include the complex matrix cases and it should obviously be the conjugate transpose, where the matrices should be unitary if I am in a complex vectorspace, so that $v'M^\dagger M v= v'v$.

Am I right that it is just $v'M^TMv$ in the real case and $v'M^\dagger M v$ in the complex case (where unitary is immediate).

Comment: This is really hard to decipher. Are your representations defined over $\mathbb{R}$ or over $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: @darijgrinberg for the 95% of my question they are over $\Bbb R$, for the initial and final comment, I generalize to the $\Bbb C$ rep case, where they are unitary matrices

Comment: This ended up being a novel, dang it.

Comment: OK, so let me state what I know: Let $V$ be a left representation of a group $G$ over a field $F$. Then, you can easily define a right representation of $G$ on $V^\ast$ by the rule $\left(fg\right)\left(v\right) = f\left(gv\right)$ for all $f \in V^\ast$, $g \in G$ and $v \in V$. You can turn this right representation "back" into a left representation of $G$ by setting $gf := fg^{-1}$ for all $f \in V^\ast$ and $g \in G$. (This is how right representations are usually translated into left representations or vice versa.) How does this translate into the language of matrices? ...

Comment: ... Well, let $\rho_V : G \to \operatorname{GL}\left(V\right)$ be the original left representation of $G$. Let $\kappa_{V^\ast} : G \to \operatorname{GL}\left(V^\ast\right)^{\operatorname{op}}$ be the right representation of $G$ on $V^\ast$ we constructed on our first step. Finally, let $\rho_{V^\ast} : G \to \operatorname{GL}\left(V^\ast\right)$ be the left representation of $G$ on $V^\ast$ we obtained by turning $\kappa_{V^\ast}$ "back" into a left representation. Then, if we identify endomorphisms of $V$ and $V^\ast$ with matrices (choosing dual bases for $V$ and $V^\ast$), we ...

Comment: ... have $\kappa_{V^\ast}\left(g\right) = \left(\rho_V\left(g\right)\right)^T$ for each $g \in G$, and we have $\rho_{V^\ast}\left(g\right) = \left(\kappa_{V^\ast}\left(g\right)\right)^{-1} = \left(\left(\rho_V\left(g\right)\right)^T\right)^{-1}$ for each $g \in G$. You probably meant one of these formulas. This works over every field -- but if you define $V^\ast$ differently over $F = \mathbb{C}$ (as some do, unfortunately), then you probably need to make modifications to these formulas as well.

Comment: Thanks very much @darijgrinberg I'll interpret this and convert it into an answer (unless you wish to). This isn't for a class, so I won't see it as a formula, so no problem for working over $\Bbb C$ or otherwise.

Comment: Feel free to convert this into an answer!